Create tabs in gmail extension app use apps script
I'm working on an email extension program similar to Copper, using Google's Apps Script. It has three tabs, and when I click on one, I expect only the bottom part of the tab to refresh to load data. I can use updateCard to refresh the entire card, but I haven't found a method to refresh only a part. I checked the doc, there's no refresh part api.
Does anyone have experience to share on this?

